# Determine if collection is of type IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, types

How to determine if object is of type IEnumerable <T>?

Code:

```
namespace NS {
    class Program {
        static IEnumerable<int> GetInts() {
            yield return 1;
        }
        static void Main() {
            var i = GetInts();
            var type = i.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NS.1.Program+<GetInts>d__0
```

If I change GetInts to return IList, everything is OK 
the output is:

```
 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

And this returns false:

```
namespace NS {
    class Program {
        static IEnumerable<int> GetInts() {
            yield return 1;
        }
        static void Main() {
            var i = GetInts();
            var type = i.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(type.Equals(typeof(IEnumerable<int>)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you mean the **collection**, then just `as`:

```
var asEnumerable = i as IEnumerable<int>;
if(asEnumerable != null) { ... }
```

However, I'm assuming (from the example) that you have a `Type`:

The *object* will never be "of" type `IEnumerable<int>` - but it might *implement* it; I would expect that:

```
if(typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {...}
```

would do. If you don't know the `T` (`int` in the above), then check all the implemented interfaces:

```
static Type GetEnumerableType(Type type) {
    if (type.IsInterface && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (intType.IsGenericType
            && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)) {
            return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call:

```
Type t = GetEnumerableType(type);
```

if this is null, it isn't `IEnumerable<T>` for any `T` - otherwise check `t`.

Comment: Just remember that `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @Tymek indeed - I do quite a lot of library work that handles primitive, inbuilt types and collections - and it is virtually always necessary to pull out scenarios such as `string` *before* applying generalizations, for exactly those reasons.

Comment: if the type is ICollection<T>, which implements IEnumerable<T>, the if statement doesn't evaluate to true.  Is there a way to tell that it is IEnumerable<T> or any of its subclasses?

Comment: There's a bug. The GetEnumerableType function does not work: for example, IEnumerable<int> in input will return null. This is because IEnumerable<int> implements IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<>. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 20):

Since IEnumerable<T> inherit IEnumerable (non generic) and if you don't need to know when a type is just IEnumerable  and not IEnumerable<T> then you can use:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(srcType))
```

Comment: string is also IEnumerable, and above check return true for string type.

Answer (score 14):

Same technique as Marc's answer, but Linqier:

```
namespace NS
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
        {
            yield return 1;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var i = GetInts();
            var type = i.GetType();
            var isEnumerableOfT = type.GetInterfaces()
                .Any(ti => ti.IsGenericType
                     && ti.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
            Console.WriteLine(isEnumerableOfT);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> How to determine if object is of type
>   IEnumerable <T>?

Please feel free to use this fine, ultra small, generic extension method to determine if any object implements IEnumerable interface. It extends the **Object** type, so you can execute it using any instance of any object you're using.

```
public static class CollectionTestClass
{
    public static Boolean IsEnumerable<T>(this Object testedObject)
    {
        return (testedObject is IEnumerable<T>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i` is of type `NS.1.Program+<GetInts>d__0`, which is a *subtype* of `IEnumerable<int>`. Thus, you can use either

```
if (i is IEnumerable<int>) { ... }
```

or `IsAssignableFrom` (like in Marc's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is` keyword.

```
[TestFixture]
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
    {
        yield return 1;
    }

    [Test]
    static void Maasd()
    {
        var i = GetInts();
        Assert.IsTrue(i is IEnumerable<int>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> type.GetInterface("IEnumerable") != null && type.IsGenericType

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to solve this should be simple..  You first write code that returns the generic arguments (or argument in your case) of the `IEnumerable<T>` then write another line to make a comparison of the argument type you desire to compare to the type contained in the `IEnumerable<T>` object (`int`, in your case).  I have an example that displays two simple functions that handles both tasks.

```
    public static Type GetEnumerableArgumentType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        else
            return null;            
    }        

    public static bool EnumerableContainsArgumentType(Type tEnumerable, Type tGenArg)
    {
        return GetEnumerableArgumentType(tEnumerable) == tGenArg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for this who just wants to know how to return true or false on if an object is or inherits from IEnumerable, I've used Marcs original answer to create this generic method I'm now using.

```
private static bool ImplementsIEnumerable<T>(T obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        if (type.IsInterface && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            return true;
        }
        foreach (Type interfaceUsed in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (interfaceUsed.IsGenericType
                && interfaceUsed.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```